# Pointing out the mistake

Tags: discussion

[What would happen if you shot an F-16's fuel tank?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/47159/what-would-happen-if-you-shot-an-f-16s-fuel-tank/47160#47160)
Now, As I see

- No Fiction
- No spam video link (I Didn't think, adding a small paragraph would mess up my question so bad in the past)
- Simple question without major grammar issues (Except toward you/towards you)

So What did I do wrong this time and why is my question isn't considered as part of an aviation? (Also since it was about shooting an aeroplane, does this mean questions like "Artillery vs Aircraft" aren't OK too?)

Comment: "*What would happen if you shot an F-16's fuel tank?*": seems a random question, not really focused on a visible aspect, potentially very open (will the bullet also hit the pilot?). You could possibly attract more interest with "Are F-16 tanks, or more generally war aircraft tanks, resistant to bullets to prevent fire or explosion?".

Comment: @mins "Question closed REASON:Too Broad" even if you would say that, It wouldnt be same for both IL2 Sturnnovik (Love that sim) and F4E P2

Answer (score 5):

You were mainly curious about bullets and fuel tanks (I think). A [simple search](https://www.google.com/search?q=bullet%20shot%20at%20fuel%20tank) would have shown this non-aviation topic has been investigated before. Spoiler: [no explosion](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/mythbusters-database/shooting-gas-tank/).

I have [recommended](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3447/14897) on the other post—based on the similar case I linked—to join [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) to ask before posting. Will this question be good? How can I improve it?

English mistakes I'm fine with and happy to edit, many of us are.

But I also mentioned 2 times before, this is the third, about line breaks (even explained how to use them). It makes the editor's job easier and more inviting, and makes for a nicer presentation for the reader. This is also mentioned by the answer you accepted on the other post:

> (...) you don't edit/format your post (...)

**Today's lessons:**

- Find aviation angle
- Is it really about aviation?
- Google (or even Bing)
- Join the chat
- Don't worry about the English
- Use line breaks / format

From my previous answer the issues were:

> a spam video, no line breaks, no context, and no simple research shown.

Here still no line breaks, no context, and no simple research shown.

---

**RE comment:**

> It has to be aviation since knowledge of a pilot or an F-16 mechanic is needed to answer it, Aviation fuel is LOT different from the car fuel thus Fuel in the Mythbusters vid is different from the fuel used in the Aviation

Feel free to edit the question to highlight that. That *alone* shows you have done research. But the specificity of the rifle and aircraft model are not needed—aircraft by role should be enough, e.g., fighter, airliner, light piston, etc.

> I cant join the chat because of the internet

Then check all the answers on your meta posts, and stick to the recommendations you've received, that should help plenty.

> how do I use linebreaks in the comments

You can't, but please do for questions/answers.

Comment: Is it really about aviation ? A:It has to be aviation since knowledge of a pilot or an F-16 mechanic is needed to answer it, Aviation fuel is LOT different from the car fuel thus Fuel in the Mythbusters vid is different from the fuel used in the Aviation///I cant join the chat because of the internet ! yes I am stealing Wi-Fi from the distance and it goes off repeatedly !///First time I wrote that question details, It was so basic that I couldnt find a way to fix it, also how do I use linebreaks in the comments ? which HTML code I have to use ?

Comment: @JonathanIrons - see update above.

Comment: @JonathanIrons "Aviation fuel is LOT different from the car fuel" not that much: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12184/1467

Comment: @Federico There are lots of different aviation fuels ! AVGAS that can be used both on tiny ass C172's and cars/ JET-A that 737's use and different airlines use different densities/--------Fuel that USAF jet fighters use------/SR71 Blackbird fuel that a match can't burn !

Comment: @ymb1 (Sorry for using !'s excessively)  "Caliber and plane name isnt needed" Dafuq ? Mig 21and F4E has differently armored different steel plates and they are made by different material strenghts/densites/methods ! and caliber makes an difference ! imagine difference between 22LR and 20MM rifles make ! and I wondered if the fuel would leak/blackout in a maneuver ! And can you please edit my question according to the "research that alone shows my research" so I can get an better "grip" of line breaks ?

Comment: @ymb1 also look to the fuel type comment I made a 2 comments above

Comment: @JonathanIrons - any argument is lost when the tone is 'tiny ass' and 'dafuq'. Invest more time learning how to write in a professional manner, then your questions will become clear and on-topic.

Comment: @ymb1 When this site is the only place you can use English, you forget being formal in "Comments Sect", also, can you please give me some examples about informal phrases I used in my questions so I can correct them (Other than word "XHead" I used when I was kind of "mad"),Also, my "Can you edit my question according to the research so I can get a better understanding of using linebreaks" request is still "active" and sorry, I dont know the correct word I should have used instead of "Active" because my mind vocabulary isn't that "big"