# The community's reaction to bad questions

Tags: discussion, comments

Per the [comments on the most recent example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48715/14897), it seems like it's an ongoing issue that is bothering some users.

Objectively there are far worse questions with plenty of up-votes, questions from established users. And questions whose answers are readily available online. But sometimes it's a matter of the question hitting the Hot Network Questions, or it's the case of the answer being too good. I've seen the latter more. I'm just getting that out of the way.

If we are being fair, a heavily down-voted question in a streak from a user, equally does not call for up-voting [tongue-in-cheek answers](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/48665/14897) (see [here](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3373/14897)).

My two cents:

- If you don't like a bad streak of questions, down-vote or flag or VTC, and move on.
- If you suspect rep-farming, flag it for the moderators.
- If the user feels they're being unfairly targeted, they can post here on meta (we've seen it done before more than once)...
- ... but even with our guidance, [the streak continued](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3450/14897).
- Therefore, save your frustration (the [help center says so](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)).
- Highly down-voted questions do not make it to the [main page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) already.
- I've vented before in chat about the repeated erroneous calling of the 747-8 as 747 - 800, but if a user doesn't see what others have revised in their posts more than once, I won't waste my time any further editing or mentioning it.
- We have previously established that [research is not required](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1551/14897) (I don't agree with it, neither do I agree with the plagiarism policy, but I do respect the consensus).
- See top point: I can just move on. Especially that previous constructive comments didn't clearly work.
- We don't answer the question *just* for the user, we answer it for the future readers too. The latest flaps question is a valid one, even if was badly worded. And I did learn something new when I answered it.

What I am getting at is save your frustration, answer/edit it if you can/want, and let's avoid the comments that do not follow the Be Nice policy. If being nice (trying to help) failed, then there are other better tools than commenting.

---

For those coming late and those under 10k:

- The comments have been removed
- As was the tongue-in-cheek answer
- Most of the down-votes have been reversed on the latest question
- The question has been improved.

Comment: well put. I think people (including me at times! I'm no exception) just forget that if the question diesnt interest you to just move on to one which might

Comment: If you thought it was a bad question, why did you answer it?

Comment: @DanHulme `... The latest flaps question is a valid one...`

Comment: I think one important thing missing from this discussion is downvote vs vote-to-close.  They are often conflated but they are very different.  A downvoted but open question is very answerable, but not useful, clear, or well-researched. A closed question is off-topic, a bad fit for a Q&A site, or impossible to really answer, but may be clear or well-researched.  Don't vote to close as "too broad" just because it's a dumb or naive question.