# Can votes to close a question as a duplicate ever be over-ruled by moderators?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, moderators

Can votes to close a question as a duplicate ever be over-ruled by moderators, if a sufficient argument is provided that the question is not a duplicate?

This appears to be a related question -- [Should moderators step in when there is a disagreement over leaving open / closing posts?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/should-moderators-step-in-when-there-is-a-disagreement-over-leaving-open-closi?rq=1)

Comment: I think it's a dupe to the linked post (even on meta there are dupes :) ), unless something was unclear over there, then it's better to highlight it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderators can close, reopen, delete, or undelete questions regardless of existing votes. They can also remove it from the review queue.

As to when/if they should, the question you linked to is a good discussion.